# Python: How to error protect reading a csv/xlsx file with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Just new to Python and pandas. I like pandas because it, so far as my need at the moment is, is easy to read from and write to excel sheets.

However I like to  put the reading in a try, like the following code that I use for 'normal' files.

```
filename = "./_csv/Orders.xlsx"
_sheetname = "Orders"
try:
 with open(filename, 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()
  if not content:
     print("no data in file " + fileName)
     #do create a new datagram
  with open(fileName, 'w') as outp:
     # add more content
     add_more_content()
     outp.write(content)
except IOError as e:
    print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

But I would like to use something similar when opening a csv or xlsx file using pandas.

```
result = pandas.read_excel("./_csv/Orders.xlsx", sheet_name="Orders",  header=None)
```

How should I continue with try and with?

```
filename = "./_csv/Orders.xlsx"
_sheetname = "Orders"
try
  with ?? pandas.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=_sheetname,  header=None) as ???
   add_more_content()
   #and save it.
except IOError as e:
  print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
except:
  print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

By everything that I did try I get "Unexpected error: <class 'AttributeError'>".

For the moment I check with something similar as the first top sample code if the file exists, and if there is content, but is of course expensive when I have to read 400Mb on data.

I see at the Pandas doc's no sample or any note about this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "./_csv/Orders.xlsx"
_sheetname = "Orders"

try:
    df= pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=_sheetname,  header=None)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print("FileNotFoundError({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I use it with 'with', because I want handling and adding more data inside the 'with' handler. ( btw, I did add two lines to explain it a little better. )

Comment: You cannot use 'with' with pandas.  You can achieve what you are trying to do easily by first reading and error capturing with pandas, then appending more data to the dataframe, and finally writing the dataframe back to a file.